# Flutter emulator toolbar is not showing

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-layout

[image]

My emulator tool bar is not showing in android studio I have also activated emulator toolbar option in emulator settings.

Screen shots of emulator toolbar and and settings are as follows:

[image]